# angular-cli: ng new my-dream-app error

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to create a new Angular 2 app using Angular CLI, but getting an error.

Here's the information I could think of collecting:

**Version Information**

When I run:

```
ng version
```

I get:

```
(node:3184) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
angular-cli: 0.1.0
node: 6.1.0
os: win32 x64
```

**Error Information**

When I run:

```
ng new my-dream-app
```

I get:

```
(node:176) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
Cannot find module 'config-chain'
Error: Cannot find module 'config-chain'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:438:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:386:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't just dump the error and expect someone to answer. What were you trying to achieve? What is the desired result? What line is trowing the error? What have you tried so far to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that when I tried to install webdriver-manager as non-global NPm dependency into the project generated by Angular CLI.

So, here are a couple of things to try, based on the difference between my environment and tries, and your tries and the versions written in your question.

- Ignore "node:88754", this is the one safe to bypass
- Upgrade NPM to latest version, for me that was 3.9.0

  ```
  npm update -g npm
  ```
- Try to install "webdriver-manager" globally

  ```
  npm install -g webdriver-manager
  ```

  There are issues with current NPM that might get you errors. The current workaround is to just retry for a couple of times :(
- Update Angular CLI version (mine says "1.0.0**-beta.1**")

  ```
  npm install -g angular-cli
  ```

  Make sure `ng --version` returns something equal to or higher than mine.

Not sure if this will fix it for you 100%, but we can take it from there and see what you get then.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall angular-cli with cmd: 
**npm uninstall angular-cli**
And reinstall with the cmd:
**npm install -g angular-cli**

Hop that will help you.

Answer (score -1):

great help!!! thanks.
i had this message on Console when tried to create an angular project. ng new tour-of-heroes.... then and i get this error:

Error: Cannot Find module 'source-map-resolve'
......

i try this and it works.

npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest

Comment: There's already an answer that prescribes this sequence of commands. You're not adding anything new with this answer.